# Disable hash in vite script - multiple entry points for chrome extension

Tags: vite

I'm trying to write a chrome extension.   I've found a way to create multiple
pages and a background script, but the background script contains a hash and is
placed into the `dist/assets` folder. I would like to output just 'dist/background.js'.  Alternatively (and maybe better) I would like to have my manifest updated to contain the actual script name with the hash.

Here's my `vite.config.ts`

```js
import { defineConfig, BuildOptions } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
const { resolve } = require('path')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    // lib: {
    //   entry: resolve(__dirname, 'background.ts'),
    //   name: 'background',
    //   fileName: format => `background.{format}.js`
    // },
    rollupOptions: {
      // output: {
      //   format: 'cjs'
      // },
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        popup: resolve(__dirname, 'popup/index.html'),
        options: resolve(__dirname, 'options/index.html'),
        background: resolve(__dirname, 'background.ts'),
      },
      // output: {
      //   format: 'cjs'
      // }
    }
  }
})
```

I've tried a few things and some are shown here commented out, but I couldn't get anything to work how I wanted.   Finally I was able to get it to work if I create a separate `vite.config.background.ts` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
const { resolve } = require('path')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: resolve(__dirname, 'background.ts'),
      output: {
        format: "esm",
        file: "dist/background.js",
        dir: null,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

And edit my build script to build it after the other config:

```json
"build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build && vite build --config vite.config.background.ts",
```

But is there any way to use just one file, or to generate the manifest and use the hashed
file name?   Right now it is a static json file.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing which isn't optimal.  It's just hard to believe that you can specify multiple inputs which produce multiple outputs, but not define output settings for each...  Structure:

```
+-- dist (output directory)
+-- options (options page)
+-- popup (popup page)
+-- public (contents copied directly to dist
|   +-- background.js (generated background script from '/background.ts')
|   +-- manifest.json (extension manifest)
+-- scripts (scripts used in build)
|   +-- watch.mjs (script for 'yarn watch')
+-- src (main page)
+-- background.ts
```

So manifest.json is in the public directory which is copied to the root of dist.  And the background script build puts the output `background.js` in that folder too for the main build to copy as part of the 'main' page.

**scripts/watch.mjs**

```js
import { createServer, build } from 'vite'

/**
 * @type {(server: import('vite').ViteDevServer) => Promise<import('rollup').RollupWatcher>}
 */
function watchBackground(server) {
  return build({
    configFile: 'vite.config.background.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    build: {
      watch: {},
    },
  })
}

/**
 * @type {(server: import('vite').ViteDevServer) => Promise<import('rollup').RollupWatcher>}
 */
 function watchMain(server) {
  return build({
    configFile: 'vite.config.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    build: {
      watch: {},
    },
  })
}

// bootstrap
const server = await createServer({ configFile: 'vite.config.ts' })

await server.listen()
await watchBackground(server) // outputs to public/background.js, so run first
await watchMain(server)
```

**vite.config.background.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
const { resolve } = require('path')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: resolve(__dirname, 'background.ts'),
      output: {
        format: "esm",
        file: "public/background.js",
        dir: null,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig, BuildOptions } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
const { resolve } = require('path')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        popup: resolve(__dirname, 'popup/index.html'),
        options: resolve(__dirname, 'options/index.html'),
      },
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: In vite.config.background, Types of property 'dir' are incompatible. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
This was only a watch script, how about the build script?

Answer (score 1):

Running multiple rollup builds with one vite build command is [not supported](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2039#issuecomment-779356090) but you can generate a manifest file directly from vite. To generate it simply set [`build.manifest`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-manifest) to true (but I am not sure if this will contain everything that you need for a manifest file for a web plugin though).